Scipy's shgo ignores a constraint
When I run the following code
from scipy import optimize
from math import log

bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))

def finite_resources(x):
    return x[0] + x[2] - 1

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': finite_resources})

def global_satisfaction(x):
    return -(log(1+x[0])/(1+x[1]*10000) + log(1+x[2])/(1+x[3]*10000))

results = dict()
print(optimize.shgo(global_satisfaction, bounds, constraints=cons))

I get
 message: Optimization terminated successfully.
 success: True
     fun: -1.3862943611198906
    funl: [-1.386e+00]
       x: [ 1.000e+00  0.000e+00  1.000e+00  0.000e+00]
      xl: [[ 1.000e+00  0.000e+00  1.000e+00  0.000e+00]]
     nit: 1
    nfev: 18
   nlfev: 5
   nljev: 1
   nlhev: 0

How is it that the constraint x[0]+x[2]-1=0 is not respected in the returned 4-uple?
I hesitate to report an issue on scipy's Github.

Curiously, that looks like an SLSQP-specific solver problem. If I change the solver with optimize.shgo(global_satisfaction, bounds, constraints=cons, minimizer_kwargs={'method': 'COBYQA'}), it now respects the constraint. I wonder why it does that. "trust-constr" also finds a solution, though it respects the constraint a little less.

OK thanks. So you think this is a good issue for scipy's Github?
